# RSS escaped HTML

Tags: html, rss

My understanding of RSS's "escaped HTML" is that something like this:

HTML:

```
1 &lt; 3
```

becomes (RSS):

```
1 &amp;lt; 3
```

So, then, should this:

```
<img src="http://somehost/someimage?a=foo&amp;b=bar" />
```

Become:

```
&lt;img src="http://somehost/someimage?a=foo&amp;amp;b=bar" /&gt;
```

(Note the `&amp;amp;` If yes, is this then invalid RSS?

```
<description>
    ...
    &#60;img src="http://d.yimg.com/a/p/ap/20110309/capt.f6...02-0.jpg?x=91&amp;y=130&amp;q=85&amp;sig=6oI7fIgN0izc9olfgY56vw--" />
</description>
```

(Additionally, is the fact that the closing > *isn't* escaped bad?)

The problem with the above <description> that I'm having is that once you decode the first layer of entities (XML) to arrive at the contents of the <description> tag, you get one long CDATA, which should be HTML. The problem is that the <img> has just a `&`, which is an invalid entity. For the massive chunk above, I get something like `<img src="....?x=1&y=2" />`, which isn't valid HTML.

Am I just looking at crappy HTML that got shoved into RSS, or am I missing something here?

Comment: `<img src="....?x=1&y=2" />` is invalid but browsers can handle it, so it's very possible the original HTML did not properly escape the ampersands in the SRC attribute. The unescaped `>` is certainly not a good thing, but again, perhaps feed readers do not choke on it. Both of these things are not done properly, but could very well work in permissive clients.

Comment: That was mostly my thinking... I stumbled across this while trying to get the page to validate at http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) Sections

```
<description><![CDATA[ <img src="http://somehost/someimage?a=foo&amp;b=bar" /> ]]>
</description>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, so I'm marking it as the accepted answer. (This question is a bit stale.) Sadly, I don't have control over what's generating the RSS. The gist here: The above RSS (in the question, not this answer) is incorrect, and using CDATA sections  (while not strictly required) would likely improve readability of the data.